# Как заменить в каждом чётном столбце матрицы (начиная с нулевого) все отрицательные по значению элементы нулём?

Tags: c#, .net

Размерность матрицы запрашивается у пользователя.(Выполнил с проверкой)
генерация(выполнил)
вывести начальную матрицу(выполнил)
Заменить в каждом чётном столбце матрицы (начиная с нулевого) все отрицательные по значению элементы нулём(не получается)-Помогите с этим, пожалуйста.

Вывести элементы обновлённой матрицы matrix в консоль построчно (выполнил)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Введите размер матрицы: ");
        bool ok = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int size);

        if (size < 0 || size > 7)
            throw new Exception("Введены невалидные данные!");

        int[,] matrix = new int[size, size];
        Random generator = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                matrix[i, j] = generator.Next(-100, 100);
                Console.Write($"{matrix[i, j]}\t");

            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                if (j % 2 == 0 && matrix[i, j] < 0)
                    matrix[i, j] = 0;
                Console.Write($"{matrix[i, j]}\t");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `(не получается)` что конкретно не получается то?

Comment: @tym32167 Я не очень понимаю, правильно ли я сделал проверку после которой заменяю элементы на 0 и как видно на скрине вторая матрица генерируется, а не вытекает из первой.

Comment: 1) `все отрицательные по значению элементы нулём`, то есть не `if (j % 2 == 0 && j < 0)`, а `if (j % 2 == 0 && matrix[j, i] < 0)`

Comment: 2) У вас не две матрицы на выходе, а одна. Вы каждый эдемент матрицы дважды выводите.

Comment: @tym32167 Как это лечиться? Я не вижу этого умножения

Comment: вы для каждой ячейки выводите `Console.Write($"{matrix[i, j]}\t\t");` дважды

Comment: все равно не понимаю, извините.

Comment: Что конкретно не понимаете то?

Comment: это вывод первой матрицы, а нужно из первой матрицы вывести вторую, в которой заменены элементы.

Comment: @tym32167 Как вывести из родительской матрицы вторую, в который заменены элементы по условию

Comment: у вас сейчас одна матрица. У вас нет первой или второй - она одна у вас. Если вам надо 2 матрицы, вам надо вторую матрицу создать в вашем коде.

Comment: @tym32167 хм.. либо вы не поняли, либо я. В коде видно, как генерируется первая матрица с помощью класса Random. Я не понимаю как из этой матрицы взять обновленную согласно условию if (j % 2 == 0 && matrix[j, i] < 0)
                        matrix[j, i] = 0; и вывести эту обновленную матрицу

Comment: @tym32167 что для этого нужно сделать?

Comment: вот это `int[,] matrix = new int[size, size];` - выделение памяти под матрицу. Поглядите на свой код, и вы поймете, что память вы выделете только для одной матрицы. У вам нет второй матрицы совсем. Вы создали первую матрицу, заполняете её случайными числами, выводите, потом обновляете ёё элемент и выводите его снова, при этом зачем то поменяв индекст строки и столбца.

Comment: @tym32167 Если вам интересно, то я решил эту задачу без создания второй матрицы. Сейчас выше изменю код и дам скриншот

Comment: Конечно интересно! Я думаю, если у вас есть ответ, его лучше ответом запостить, а не править вопрос.

Comment: @tym32167 это хорошее решение?

Comment: Да, вполне хорошее.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("Введите размер матрицы: ");
    bool ok = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int size);

    if (size < 0 || size > 7)
        throw new Exception("Введены невалидные данные!");

    int[,] matrix = new int[size, size];
    Random generator = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            matrix[i, j] = generator.Next(-100, 100);
            Console.Write($"{matrix[i, j]}\t");

        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (j % 2 == 0 && matrix[i, j] < 0)
                matrix[i, j] = 0;
            Console.Write($"{matrix[i, j]}\t");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```